# How to use k-means between binary images?

Tags: c++, k-means, opencv3.0

I'll reword my question because it was not clear enough.So, k-means clustering aims to partition "n observations" into k clusters in which each observation belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean. In my case "observations" are "binary images"; indeed, I want to cluster the set of binary images into k cluster, because this set of images are close. I want to partition them to k closter in order to represent each cluster per one image (Characteristic image).
I try to implement @Miki's proposal ("matrix" MxN where N = image.rows*image.cols). But I don't know how to convert "matrix" to cv::InputArray in order to use the k-means method of opencv.
This is a part of my code:

```
 CString numImage
 int i,j,k,val,Nx,Ny,***matrice;
 FILE *fsource,*fdist;
 //memory allocation
 matrix = (int***)malloc(100*sizeof(int**)); //100 binary images
 for (int q=0 ;q < 100;q++)
 { 
     numImage.Format("%d",q);
     fsource = fopen("path_to_image" + numImage + ".txt","r");         
     fscanf(fsource,"%d %d",&Nx,&Ny);

     //memory allocation
     matrice[q] = (int**)malloc(Nx*sizeof(int*));
     for(i = 0 ; i < Nx ;i++)
         matrice[q][i] = (int*)malloc(Ny*sizeof(int));

     // Loading data
     for( i = 0 ; i < Nx ; i++ )
     {
         for( j = 0 ; j < Ny ; j++ )
             {
                 fscanf(fsource,"%d",&val);
                 matrice[q][i][j] = val;
              }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ypu don't apply kmeans to images, but on points in a N-dimensional space. So please clarify what you're trying to do. Currently it doesn't make any sense

Comment: k-means clustering aims to partition "n observations" into k clusters in which each observation belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean. In my case "observations" are "binary images"; indeed, I want to cluster the set of binary images into  k cluster, because this set of images are close. I want to partition them into K cluster to represent later, each group by a single Characteristic image. I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: So each one of your N-dimensional points is an _unrolled_ image, where N = image.rows*image.cols. You can feed kmeans with a matrix MxN, where M is the number of your images. Pay attention that if your images are large (N is large) you'll need a very large amount of images (M) to make some sense, or you'll incur in the _curse of dimensionality_

Comment: Also, the euclidean distance may not be appropriate for binary data, but more on that only if needed.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't defined "closeness" between two images.

Comment: I try to implement Miki's proposal ("matrix" M*N where  N = image.rows*image.cols). But I don't know how to convert "matrix" to cv::InputArray.

Answer (score 0):

this is a part of my code:

```
     CString numImage
     int i,j,k,val,Nx,Ny,***matrice;
     FILE *fsource,*fdist;
     //memory allocation
     matrix = (int***)malloc(100*sizeof(int**)); //100 binary images
     for (int q=0 ;q < 100;q++)
     { 
         numImage.Format("%d",q);
         fsource = fopen("path_to_image" + numImage + ".txt","r");         
         fscanf(fsource,"%d %d",&Nx,&Ny);

         //memory allocation
         matrice[q] = (int**)malloc(Nx*sizeof(int*));
         for(i = 0 ; i < Nx ;i++)
             matrice[q][i] = (int*)malloc(Ny*sizeof(int));

         // Loading data
         for( i = 0 ; i < Nx ; i++ )
         {
             for( j = 0 ; j < Ny ; j++ )
                 {
                     fscanf(fsource,"%d",&val);
                     matrice[q][i][j] = val;
                  }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please edit your original question. Don't put changes as "answers", because this clearly isn't an answer!

Comment: sorry i am new in this forum, I have reworded my question.